# Appending Vowel Location Python

Tags: python, indices, enumerate

I am trying to figure out why I am getting an empty list when this code is ran. The goal is to take a string, find the index of any vowels and append that index to a list. With an index starting at one instead of zero. Any tips where the error might be occurring would be great! If there is a general oversight you notice please let me know. Relatively new to python. thanks

```
def vowel_indices(word):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    vowel_idx = []
    word.lower() 
    for idx, letter in enumerate(word, start = 1):
        if letter == vowels:
            vowel_idx.append(idx) 
        return vowel_idx
```

Answer (score 1):

`if letter == vowels:` should be `if letter in vowels:`

vowels is a list and a string can never be equal to a list and you should also move the return out of the loop as that will stop the function in it's track the first time it loops through

Answer (score 1):

Method `lower` does not modify the string *in-place* (strings are *immutable*), so you should instead do:

```
word = word.lower()
```

Then to check for the membership of a character in the list of `vowels`, you should use the `in` operator and not `==`:

```
if letter in vowels:
```

And then the `return` statement should not be placed inside the `for` loop as this will make the function return immediately after the first iteration, which is not what you intend:

```
for idx, letter in enumerate(word, start = 1):
    if letter in vowels:
        vowel_idx.append(idx) 
return vowel_idx
```

---

On an additional note, you can be less verbose and do the entire operation using a *list comprehension*:

```
def vowel_indices(word):
    return [idx for idx, l in enumerate(word.lower(), 1) if l in vowels]
```

Comment: Also the return statement is out of place.

Comment: @Alex Yes, that too

Comment: Thanks that clarified a lot for me!

Answer (score 1):

**It work great**

```
def vowel_indices(word):
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    word.lower()
    indexes = [index for c,index in zip(word,range(len(word))) if c in vowels]
    print(indexes)
```

Comment: This doesn't work how OP wants and why are you using `zip`?

Comment: zip is use for getting location of character in words and zip combine both word and range()

Comment: But why are you using it over `enumerate`?

Comment: Read the documentation. .https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip   Demo:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python3_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMV3MzaFpHbW1MZG8